# Martingale Decomposition

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, stochastic-analysis

Is it possible to decompose a discrete-time martingale $(M_n)$ uniquely into two processes
$$M_n=M_n^I+A_n$$ where $(M^I_n)$ is a martingale with independent increments and $(A_n)$ is a martingale? If no, under which condition(s) on $(M_n)$, do we have this kind of decomposition?

Comment: Yes. (Hint: Let $M_n^I$ be something very trivial; or, if you want something slightly less trivial, add and subtract.)

Comment: For the first (*very trivial*) part, yes, $M_n^I = 0$ is valid. For the second (only slightly *less trivial*) part, add and subtract a martingale $(S_n)$ with independent increments that is independent of $(M_n)$.

Comment: I edited my question. Actually what I mean is an unique decomposition similar to Doob decomposition.

Comment: Then, the answer is obviously "no", by considering examples in the same spirit as the ones I gave.

Comment: thanks cardinal. I again edited the question. I would like to learn under which conditions it is possible to do. Any reference would also be helpful.

Comment: I should be clear that in the examples of adding and subtracting another nontrivial martingale, it may require augmenting the filtration to which the process is adapted. :-)